# Prevent firestore writes?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using firestore to store user data for my app. When the user has no internet connection and uses the app, it still allows the user to make changes via offline persistence. Once the app regains internet connection, it will attempt to sign the user in. However, the offline edits are still made to the database even if the user is signed out. How do I cancel those offline writes if the user cannot sign in? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the offline persistance with this code:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
    Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#configure-offline-persistence).